# Haskell: Get and remove from list

Tags: haskell

I'm having a problem with getting and dropping the first value from list in the recursive function.

Here is the code:

```
removeDuplicates a u = [if a == [] then u else removeDuplicates newA newU
                       | let newU = (head a):u 
                       | let newA = tail a]
```

And error:

```
Illegal parallel list comprehension: use -XParallelListComp
```

And another idea:

```
removeDuplicates a u = [if a == [] then u else removeDuplicates (tail a) newU
                       | let newU = (head a):u]
```

And another error:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
    Expected type: [a0]
      Actual type: [[a0]]
    In the return type of a call of `removeDuplicates'
    In the expression: removeDuplicates (tail a) newU
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: At the moment only thing I'm trying to do with this function is moving all items from first list to second with recursive function one by one. After that I will add few more things to remove duplicate values from list.

Comment: Could you make clearer what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to use list comprehensions or let .. in clause? To move the elements one by one, the code of @Apocalisp does the job

Comment: The `ParallelListComp` is caused by you using `[... | ... | ...]`. Unless you're doing something fancy, it's always `[... | ...]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do:

```
removeDuplicates [] u = u
removeDuplicates (x:xs) u = removeDuplicates xs (x:u)
```

But this is basically `reverse`:

```
reverse = foldl (flip (:)) []
```

Comment: I was going to downvote, and then I read the full question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do homework or study haskell, there is `nub` function in `Data.List`.

Comment: Yes I know about nub function and yes it is for school and I can't use it.

Comment: Is it cheating to lift the code from the source of `nub`? Whether or not it is, for the sake of learning you should probably try to implement it yourself before looking in the "back of the book".

Comment: OK, Next time will add tag homework.. Just finished my function, haskell is really great language but it is hard to get used to it :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting list comprehension and "infinite type: a0 = [a0]" errors is because the compiler is reading your brackets as defining a list. Use the syntax

```
f x = a + b
      where a = 10
            b = 20
```

or

```
f' x = let a = 3
           b = 4
       in a + b
```